diesel smell out of clothing/Machine
Little More help needed, can I used white vinegar to get the smell of diesel out,
do I soak the clothing in cold or warm water with the white vinegar?, what other products can I used? the smell in the washing machine.

If you don't get it right, you'll contaminate everything else you try to wash it in too. IMO the best thing is to bin it. And if it was caused by splashback when refuelling a) stand to one side, b) never try to brim the tank.
